# Chrome print to PDF with background colors

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, pdf, printing

I have page based on Bootstrap with Flat UI css and I'd like to print it (save to PDF).

But it can't print color of headlines and color of progress bar. I saw tutorials there, but it didn't work.

[Here is live demo.](http://apps.8u.cz/flatui/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like the folloing code snippet in [Bootstrap css](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/3efa9c46a40e49109e7a14d58ee7f8b170a3d17b/less/print.less#L13)   causing this issue, I just removed it for mine .

```
@media print {
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
        background: transparent !important;
        color: #000 !important; // Black prints faster: h5bp.com/s
        box-shadow: none !important;
        text-shadow: none !important;
    }
```

Comment: This was helpful. I was searching why is my browser not printing any background colors. Little did I know that my issues were caused by Bootstrap "reset"/"normalize" styles.

Comment: Indeed very helpful. As the print css is hard to debug in the browser, this was causing quite some hassle. I suggest creating a custom bootstrap css file from their site without the media print part.

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable the option to include background graphics. Please see below

[image]

Comment: Yes, but as you can see in your image, progress bars are still gray and headlines black.